# Missing images in gke private images registry from gitlab ci/cd build

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

GKE private image registry is missing images. No changes to the environment have been done, this process was working fine until about 2 weeks ago. Here's the process

(This environment was handed to me and it is my first time into the CI/CD process and I am a newbie on the GKE environment as well.)

I have a GitLab pipeline that builds and deploys my app to a GKE dev environment when triggered. There are **no errors** reported in this process and it completes *using gitlab.com* in 4-5 minutes. )

The issue that manifested is that many of the images in a google private registry are no longer there, the current version is gone. The pod is trying to pull that image and it is failing with the ImagePullBackoff error, which makes sense due to the missing images. (That is most of them have disappeared, over 40 past versions are not longer in the registry, some older images are still there. )

**First**, I cannot tell how the images, from the CI/CD process, get placed into the private registry. There is only a reference to pull the registry.gitlab.com and no corresponding push to eu.gcr.io references at all (in the ci/cd files) which is the location of the gke image registry.

There are 3 files related to the ci/cd process:

```
gitlab-ci.yaml
kube-init.sh
migration.sh
```

All the secrets are in place and none have been changes. It seems there is a piece missing which moves/saves the files to the private google image registry...where would that be defined?

I can post the files in this process but since there are no errors there, I am not sure that would help. (Let me know if they are needed.)

Thanks in advance...I can't wait to get a DevOps engineer:)

-glen

Comment: Could you provide the steps taken to pull the image from the registry, and if they have been modified in any way before they started failing. According to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/partners/deploying-gitlab-anthos-gke-on-prem-cicd-pipeline#manually_deploy_the_application) the images are hosted on gitlab and aren't pushed to the gke registry.

Comment: Well, that was my dilemma. I could not see how the image was being pulled or pushed. A contractor set up the CI/CD process and when I removed that account from the project it stopped working and many, images disappeared from the Google image repo and the pod failed. So, apparently, he had created a cert to manage that relationship to the cloud repo but I could not see it. When it was created a token could not be created for a group or a single project. So the token was associate with his account. That has changed now, a token was issued and the process can pull the image from GitLab now.

Comment: Could you provide the steps taken to solve your issue as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

As a summary of the conclusion reached in the comments:

The images are hosted on gitlab and aren't pushed to the GKE registry. as can be seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/partners/deploying-gitlab-anthos-gke-on-prem-cicd-pipeline#manually_deploy_the_application).

The issue OP had was related to the token created for the pipeline from Google Cloud Platform to Gitlab, as it was linked to the previous account which is no longer associated. A new token was issued and the images can be pulled from Gitlab.